# Trouble with 'this' in Backbone View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So I have a backbone view for a google map.

```
'use strict';

var MapView = Backbone.View.extend({
  id: 'map-container',

  initialize: function() {
    this.model.set('map', new google.maps.Map(this.el, this.model.get('mapOptions')));
    this.render();
    this.map = this.model.get('map');

    this.poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
      strokeColor: '#000000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 3
    });
    this.poly.setMap(this.map);

    this.map.addListener('click', this.addLatLng);
  },

  render: function() {
    $('#map-container').replaceWith(this.el);
    return this;
  },

  addLatLng: function(event) {
    var path = this.poly.getPath();

    path.push(event.latLng);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      title: '#' + path.getLength(),
      map: this.map
    });
  }
});
```

My problem is in the addLatLng function. this.poly is undefined and I think it is because of where addLatLng is being called? But i'm not super sure. Is there a way that this.poly and this.map can be defined in addLatLng?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.map.addListener('click', this.addLatLng);` is your problem.  You are registering it to run a specific function, but that function won't be bound to any context when it runs.  You can use the Underscore `bind` function to ensure the function runs in the current context:

```
var boundAddLatLong = _.bind(this.addLatLong, this);
this.map.addListener('click', boundAddLatLong);
```

If you were using some of the [Backbone.Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) functionality (`on`, `listenTo`, etc), it provides ways to provide the context that the function should run in.  But whatever `this.map` is does not appear to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You want to make sure the method is being called in the right context.
In javascript what defines `this` is [how you invoke the function, not how you define it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

This will do the trick:

```
this.map.addListener('click', this.addLatLng.bind(this));
```